# Как прекратить действие зарегистрированного скрипта с помощью ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, c#

Имеется форма:

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit ="return $(this).jval('isvalid')">
  ...  
  <input type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick = "LoginBtnCLick" value="Войти" />
</form>
```

Если поля прошли валидацию форма сабмитится. На сервере же после проверки логина, пароля и если такие не найдены запускаю клиентский скрипт.

```
 protected void LoginBtnCLick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {         
   if (Handlers.ValidateUser(loginname.Value, password.Value)) {
     ...
   } else {
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "StartScript", "NA()", true);
   }
 }
```

И все хорошо функция NA() запускается. НО, при обновлении страницы данный скрипт снова отрабатывает, чего бы не хотелось. Пытался использовать проверку ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered, не помогло. Посоветуйте как можно сделать, чтобы скрипт отрабатывал 1 раз при нажатии на кнопку "Войти", а не при обновлении страницы. Спасибо.

Comment: создать переменную которая будет отслеживать выполнялся ли скрипт, если выполнялся, то не регистрировать, под переменной тут подразумеваю контрол с постбэком.

Comment: @VladimirT, я правильно вас понял, мне надо на кнопке создать контрол и поместить его например в Placeholder, а на Page_Load проверить имеется ли он и если нет то регистрировать скрипт?

Comment: Достаточно HidenField  в любой части страницы, и проверять, пустая она или нет, если не пустая, то не регистрировать, а если пустая то регистрировать, соответственно после выполнения скрипта задаете любое значение и отправляете постбэком.

Comment: @VladimirT, добавил в else^^ код с проверкой HiddenField if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptState.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "StartScript", "NA()", true);
                    scriptState.Value = "Loaded";
                } Теперь у меня соответственно только 1 раз выполняется даже когда по кнопке жмякаю, где-то не догоняю)

Comment: Последний комментарий не понял, теперь у вас, при наличие условия, сработало, однако при обновлении не работает? Когда вы по кнопке "жмякаете" на всех пользователях, аа-а-а, понял, при выборе пользователя скрытое поле нужно принудительно обнулять.

Comment: @VladimirT, да получается что после первого срабатывания, поле имеет значение "Loaded" и больше не вызывает скрипт. Про обнуление поля думал, но не понял где его воткнуть, как понять "при выборе пользователя"? У меня либо авторизация прошла либо нет и запускается скрипт.

Comment: судя по всему по изменению значения loginname, вам необходимо выставить scriptState.Value = "";

Comment: @VladimirT, тогда снова при "F5" запускается скрипт, палка о двух концах)

Comment: а если вместо "Loaded", записывать имя пользователя, и проверять, их на совпадение?

Comment: @VladimirT, такая же фигня) при рефреше страницы запоминает логин)

Comment: перейдите в чат.